# Lasti Full page cache module, Customer session

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, customer-session

In a custom module I had added a block to product page through xml, on the site i am using Lasti_FPC so I also added that block to dynamic_blocks in Lasti_Fpc config.xml file. 
In that block's phtml file, I am using

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
```

to check if the customer is logged in or not (to show different button for logged in vs not logged in)
but the problem is when i browse the product page before login, then after login the page still shows content for the not logged in customers.
Can anybody help me guide me, how to tackle this and which block to include in dynamic block list?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few common blocks you won't want a fullpage cache to cache.

- cart_sidebar
- catalog.compare.sidebar
- right.reports.product.viewed
- right.reports.product.compared
- right.poll
- global_messages
- messages
- sale.reorder.sidebar

There maybe more, you'll need to experiment. You can turn template hints under System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer when on your store specific scope. From there you'll be able to see each block, and what name the block is. This will help you find out which blocks shouldn't be cached by your fullpage cache.